# fail to login to website with request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

At first here is my code:

```
import requests

payload = {'name':'loginname',
        'password': 'loginpassword'}

requests.post('http://myurl/auth',data=payload,verify=False)
rl = requests.get('http://myurl/dashboard',verify=False)

print(rl.text)
```

My problem:

I get the status code 200 which means that the login was successfull.
But when i try to visit the protected page http://myurl/dashboard my output doesn't fit. It shows me the first page for login and i don't get it why.

I know there are many questions like that but i studied every answer and the docs but i dont get it.

Any help would be very nice. It drives me cracy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from what was mentioned in my answer, I don't _think_ you need the `verify=False` without `https`. Unless the `http` URL redirects you to an `https` URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object to have `requests` maintain track of your cookies, such as the login cookie which would get set after your `requests.post` login action. Quoting the[first example there:

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')

print(r.text)
# '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'
```

So in your case:

```
import requests

payload = {'name': 'loginname',
           'password': 'loginpassword'}

s = requests.Session()
r1 = s.post('http://myurl/auth', data=payload, verify=False)
if r1.status_code == 200:  # not necessary if you are sure it would login successfully
    r2 = s.get('http://myurl/dashboard', verify=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats exatly what i need! Sorry for this newbie question but i was very confused. Thank you for helping! :-)

Comment: Great that you (a) at least tried something before asking, (b) showed what you tried and (c) explained what the issue was! +1 Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks thats really nice!